# Создание списка в словаре

Tags: python

заранее благодарю всех ответивших за помощь!
Я только начинаю изучать программирование и Python в частности по книге Эрика Мэтиза.
В одном из заданий столкнулся с проблемой, необходимо с помощью цикла `while` создать словарь и вывести результат. Задание решено, код работает. Но я хочу чтоб при вводе нескольких значений с одинаковым ключом, значения создавали список а не меняли друг друга. Попытки использовать метод  `append()` увы успеха не дали, наверняка допускаю ошибку.
Буду рад любому совету, всего доброго!

```
responses = {}# начальный пустой словарь
polling_active = True # условие выполнения цикла


while polling_active: 
    name = input("\nВаше имя? ") # ввод переменной key
    response = input("Какую страну вы хотели бы посетить?")# ввод переменной value

    responses[name]=response # присвоение значения ключу
    
    repeat = input("Будут еще желающие ответить?(да/ нет)")
    if repeat == 'нет':# условие завершения цикла
        polling_active = False

        
print("\n--- Poll Results ---")
for name, response in responses.items():# вывод результата
    print(f"{name} желает посетить {response}")
```

Comment: Где в этом коде append?

Comment: После responses[name]=response пробовал несколько вариантов в том числе с циклом for, но безуспешно. Не знал какой вариант более верен поэтомувыложил работающую часть.

Comment: Вот аж два синхронно размещённых ответа с работающим `append`:-) Я постарался максимально близко остаться к вашему коду, но и второй вариант близок к нему. Задайте вопрос, если не ясно, почему у вас не работал, или включите в вопрос наиболее бликий ваш пример.

Comment: Надо выкладывать как раз неработающий код, тогда объяснят ошибки. А сейчас вы просто возьмёте работающий код и ничему не научитесь.

Comment: @Эникейщик, полностью согласен. Хотя в данном случае, полагаю, автор был близок к результату, так что уж из моего-то примера точно научится:-) (так как пример прост донельзя).

Comment: Добрый день, Благодарю за ответ! как ни обидно, но я действительно был близок  к ответу) но в responses[name]=[response] не додумался про квадратные скобки response. Крайне признателен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал так: проверяем на наличие ключа в словаре (т.е. первый ли ответ от гражданина) и если его нет, то создаем запись. А если есть, то `append` срабатывает.

```
responses = {}# начальный пустой словарь
polling_active = True # условие выполнения цикла


while polling_active: 
    name = input("\nВаше имя? ") # ввод переменной key
    response = input("Какую страну вы хотели бы посетить?")# ввод переменной value
    if name not in responses:
        responses[name]=[response] # присвоение значения ключу
    else:
        responses[name].append (response)
    
    repeat = input("Будут еще желающие ответить?(да/ нет)")
    if repeat == 'нет':# условие завершения цикла
        polling_active = False

        
print("\n--- Poll Results ---")
for name, response in responses.items():# вывод результата
    print(f"{name} желает посетить {response}")
```

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ!

Answer (score 3):

По идее можно использовать специальные словари типа [`defaultdict`](https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-collections-python/klass-defaultdict-modulja-collections/), однако таковые нужно изначально импортировать и т.д., что не есть очень хорошо.

С другой стороны, если при каждом получении очередного ключа *предположить*, что туда можно поместить некоторое значение *по умолчанию* (т.е. если такого ключа в словаре нет, то мы подставим туда необходимое), то мы можем подставлять в `responses[name]` список, если такой пары нет. Это прекрасно выполняется при помощи уже встроенной в Python функции [`dict.setdefault()`](https://pythonz.net/references/named/dict.setdefault/) — надо всего лишь подставить задать всем полям пустые списки; если же очередное поле пустое, то оно гарантированно получит пустой список; а дальше можно легко добавлять при помощи `append()` :)

Ну и ещё нужно будет распаковать получившийся список в строку, это выполняется при помощи [`delim.join(lst)`](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/python-join).

```py
responses = {}# начальный пустой словарь
polling_active = True # условие выполнения цикла

while polling_active: 
    name = input("\nВаше имя? ") # ввод переменной key
    response = input("Какую страну вы хотели бы посетить? ")# ввод переменной value
  
    responses.setdefault(name, []) # по умолчанию задаём responses[name] как []
    responses[name].append(response) # добавление значения к ключу
    
    repeat = input("Будут еще желающие ответить?(да/ нет) ")
    if repeat == 'нет':# условие завершения цикла
        polling_active = False

        
print("\n--- Poll Results ---")
for name, response in responses.items():# вывод результата
    print(f"{name} желает посетить {', '.join(response)}")
    # список превращается в разделённые запятыми слова
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

В таких случаях удобно использовать `defaultdict` из стандартного модуля `collections`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

responses = defaultdict(list) # начальный пустой словарь
...
    responses[name].append(response) # присвоение значения ключу
```

Остальной код не меняется. Если в словаре нет нужного ключа, он там автоматически появляется с указанным при инициализации словаря типом, в данном случае это `list`.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!